# Finiding sublist with with limit indexes in prolog

Tags: prolog

The predicate `subList(I1,I2,L,Sub)` holds if `Sub` is a sublist of the list `L`. `Sub` contains the elements occurring in `L` from index:  `I1` till `I2`. Here is my solution but it gives `False` when i ask for `subList(1,2,[1,2,3,4],X)`. i don't know why !

```
 sublist(_,_,[],[]).
 subList(1,I2,L,Sub):-
    length(L,X),
    X==I2,
    Sub=L.

subList(1,1,[H|T],Sub):-Sub=[H].
subList(1,0,[H|T],Sub):-Sub=[H].
subList(I1,I2,[H|T],Sub):-subListHelper(I1,I2,[H|T],[_|T2],1).

subListHelper(I1,I2,[H|T],[_|T2],Acc):-
   I1==ACC,
   I1=<I2,
   I3 is I1+1, 
   NewAcc is ACC+1,
   subListHelper(I3,I2,[T],[H|T2],NewAcc).
subListHelper(I1,I2,[H|T],[_|T2],Acc):-
   I1 \= Acc,
   I1=<I2,
   NewAcc is ACC+1, 
   subListHelper(I1,I2,[T],[_|T2],NewAcc).
```

Comment: Any one can help !!

Comment: your code has some typos (e.g., `sublist` and `subList`) or variable names mismatches (I could not understand what the role of the `T2` variable is in the last clause of `subList/4`). Could you please review your code and correct such mistakes first?